# Sequential left Joins behave as inner Joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I have the following data in 3 tables:

```
  materials          customers             sales
 -----------        -----------        --------------   
  mtrl comp         cust  comp        mtrl  cust  expqty
    1   2            22    2           1     22     1
    2   2            23    2           2     22     2
    3   2            24    2           3     23     3
    4   2            25    2           4     24     4
```

and I want to produce the following result:

```
mtrl  cust  expqty  
 1     22     1  
 2     22     2  
 3     22    null  
 4     22    null
```

In SQL Server I am using the following query:

```
select a.mtrl,b.cust,c.expqty from materials a left join customers b on a.comp=b.comp 
left join sales c on c.mtrl=a.mtrl and c.cust=b.cust where b.cust=22
```

and although I am using a left join, I loose the last 2 lines and all I get is:

```
   mtrl  cust  expqty  
     1     22     1  
     2     22     2
```

Can you advice me on what I am doing wrong or how would I achieve the desired result?

Comment: Classic `Outer Join` mistake filtering the Left table in `Where` clause when you are using `LEFT JOIN`. You need to filter the Left table records in `ON` condition

Answer (score 2):

The issue isn't the sequential joins.  The problem is the `where` clause.  This condition needs to go in an `on` clause:

```
select m.mtrl, c.cust, s.expqty
from materials m left join
     customers c
     on m.comp = c.comp and c.cust = 22 left join
     sales s
     on s.mtrl = m.mtrl and s.cust = c.cust;
```

The `where` clause filters out `NULL` values, which is what turns the outer join to an inner join.  Note that I also fixed the table aliases so they are abbreviations of the table names.

Answer (score 1):

You have put a condition from your `b` table in the `where` clause. Move it to the join condition like this:

```
select a.mtrl,
       b.cust,
       c.expqty
from materials a 
left join customers b 
    on a.comp=b.comp and b.cust=22
left join sales c 
    on c.mtrl=a.mtrl and c.cust=b.cust
```